# Uploading photos to Facebook API on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to test out uploading photos to an album using Facebook API. I am currently testing using Localhost and am trying to figure out how I can provide an appropriate url for the post to the Facebook servers. I have uploaded an image to a tmp folder in my application and have a path for that but is there anyway I can, from this path, create a url that would be appropriate for the image parameter in the query string post to Facebook when I'm using Localhost?

Comment: No, because Facebook needs to be able to access that URL to download the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a `localhost` url as an image parameter to Facebook.

If you want to test your code, upload your application to an actual server somewhere which can be accessed over Internet. and then generate a `URL` and send to to Facebook.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. I've just done this but am having problems with the url used with for the source parameter of the query string..

Comment: I solved it. Basically had forgot to distinguish between the serverside paths and public path when Facebook is accessing the server. I.e was not using var/www/xy/public/photos for server side file manipulation. Thanks for your help!